# Call a function inside a variable

Tags: jquery, function, variables

I'm using this function inside a variable

```
var MyFunction = (function () {
        //......
   function FunctionToCall() {
        //......       
    };
       //........ 
}();
```

I would like to call `FunctionToCall()` with an event handler from outside the variable like this:

```
 $('div').click(FunctionToCall());
```

Any idea?

Comment: You can not access this function from the outside unless you make it available to the outside-world from the inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably missing a return statement.
I suppose you intended something like this:

```js
var myFunction = (function() {
  var privateVar = 'Hello';
  
  return function innerFunction() {
    return privateVar;
  };
})();

console.log(myFunction());
```

Another way is to return an object with the methods that you want to access:

```js
var myThing = (function() {
  var privateVar = 'Hello';

  return {
    innerFunction1: function() {
      return privateVar;
    },
    doSomething: function(newString) {
      privateVar = newString;
    }
  };
})();


myThing.doSomething("Hi!");
console.log(myThing.innerFunction1());
```

After that you can attach anything you made accessible to your event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a static method. Thus, calling it as `MyFunction.FunctionToCall()`:

```js
var MyFunction = function() {
};

MyFunction.FunctionToCall = function() {
    console.log('MyFunction.FunctionToCall called');
};

$(function() {
    $('div').click(function() {
        MyFunction.FunctionToCall()
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Click me</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are declaring an anonymous function to the variable `MyFunction` in your code. It will be undefined. You don't want to call anything inside of an anonymous function because anonymous functions are generally immediately called.

Instead, declare your FunctionToCall as a variable outside and then you could define it inside of your anonymous block like this

```
var FunctionToCall;
(function () {
    //......
    FunctionToCall = function() {
       //......       
    };
   //........ 
}();
```

And then you can call FunctionToCall. Though I don't think this is good convention as generally you want to keep functions you use throughout your code on the same scope levels.